# How to get rid of the ugly record

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, syntax, operator-overloading

```
class c {
    private:
        int n[10];
    public:
        c();
        ~c();
        int operator()(int i) { return n[i];};
};

class cc {
    private:

    public:
        c *mass;
        cc();
        ~cc();
        c& operator*() const {return *mass;};
};
int somfunc() {
    c *c1 = new c();

    cc * cc1 = new cc();

    (*cc1->mass)(1);



    delete c1;
}
```

I've got a pointer into class cc to class c.

Is there any way to get rid of record like this:

```
(*cc1->mass)(1);
```

and write somethink like that:

```
cc1->mass(1);
```

is it impossible?

Comment: Why have so many pointers in the first place? It might be more constructive to fix the coding style rather than to worry about why a really ugly piece of code looks... really ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I saw the tags "c++" and "operator overloading", my mind alarm turns ON.

C++ operator overloading is complex, and some operators like "()" or "->" make it more difficult.

I suggest, before overloading operators, making either a global function or method with the same purpouse, test it works, and later replace it with the operator.

Global friend function example:

```
class c {
    private:
        int n[10];      

    public:
        c();
        ~c();

        // int operator()(int i) { return n[i]; } 

        // there is a friend global function, that when receives a "c" object,
        // as a parameter, or declares a "c" object, as a local variable,
        // this function, will have access to the "public" members of "c" objects,
        // the "thisref" will be removed, when turned into a method
        friend int c_subscript(c thisref, int i) ;
};

int c_subscript(c* thisref, int i)
{
  return c->n[i];
}

int main()
{
  c* objC() = new c();
  // do something with "objcC"

  int x = c_subscript(objC, 3);
  // do something with "x"

  return 0;
} // int main(...)
```

Local function ( "method" ) example:

```
class c {
    private:
        int n[10];      

    public:
        c();
        ~c();

        // int operator()(int i) { return n[i]; }

        int subscript(int i) ;
};

int c::subscript(int i)
{
  return this.n[i];
}

int main()
{
  c* objC() = new c();
  // do something with "objcC"

  int x = c->subscript(objC, 3);
  // do something with "x"

  return 0;
} // int main(...)
```

And, finally use the overloaded operator:

```
class c {
    private:
        int n[10];      

    public:
        c();
        ~c();   

        int subscript(int i) ;

        int operator()(int i) { return this.subscript(i); }
};

int c::subscript(int i)
{
  return this.n[i];
}

int main()
{
  c* objC() = new c();
  // do something with "objcC"

  int x = c->subscript(3);
  // do something with "x"

  int x = c(3);
  // do something with "x"

  return 0;
} // int main(...)
```

Note that in the final example, I keep the method with a unique identifier.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Could always do this:

```
class cc {
    private:
        c *_mass;

    public:
        c& mass() const {return *_mass;};
};
```

Now..

```
cc1->mass()(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

If `mass` were an object, not a pointer, you could use the syntax you want:

```
class cc {
  private:

  public:
    c mass;
    cc();
    ~cc();
    const c& operator*() const {return mass;};
};

…

    cc1->mass(1);
```

Comment: i want to use something like this :  c* mass;

Comment: If you make `mass` a pointer, then you must dereference it before you can use the function syntax. If you make `mass` an object, then you may use the function syntax directly. You'll have to decide which feature you want more.

Answer (score 0):

You can with

```
(*(*cc1))(1)
```

because `operator()` is applied to an object, not a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
(**cc1)(1);
```

Or

```
cc1->mass->operator()(1);
```